# Apache Spark streaming custom receiver (socket server)

Tags: java, sockets, apache-spark, serversocket, socketexception

I am trying to make a simple spark streaming application which receives multiple requests at same time via socket and the spark application respond to each request on same socket , so the pipeline goes like this "assuming the spark job is up and running and waiting for new requests":

PHP send "hello spark" via socket ==> spark handle this request and reply with "hello php"

so here i am trying to combine spark with java multi-threading 
below is the code :

```
object socket_code {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CustomReceiver")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
    try{
    println("Waiting for connection")
    val listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
    val lines = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver(listener.accept()))
    lines.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
  catch
  {
    case e:SocketException => 
        println("Could not listen on port: 9898.")
  }
  }
}


class CustomReceiver(socket: Socket)
  extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) with Logging {

  def onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
    new Thread("Socket Receiver") {
      override def run() { 

    val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    try {
    val is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())
    val os = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))//new

    val out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    while(is.available()< 1)
    {
        Thread.sleep(30)
    }
    val buf = new Array[Byte](is.available)
    is.read(buf)
    println(new String(buf))
     out.writeBytes(new String("Hello PHP"))
     out.close()
    is.close()
    socket.close()

    }
    catch {
      case e: SocketException =>
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {
   // There is nothing much to do as the thread calling receive()
   // is designed to stop by itself isStopped() returns false
  }
}
```

The spark job starts normally , but when i send data to the socket , i get this error :

```
15/10/07 11:45:32 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 failed: start at main.scala:46, took 0.114462 s
Exception in thread "Thread-26" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1214)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1202)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:778)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:762)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1389)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Error is self explanatory.  java.io.NotSerializableException: java.net.Socket. Change socket variable access modifier  as transient.

Comment: sorry but how to do that ?

Comment: Post the definition of class containing socket class

Comment: i edited the code as below:
@transient val listener = new ServerSocket(9898);
but still getting the same error

Comment: Even client socket (normal Socket) should be transient.

Comment: you mean this one :
class CustomReceiver(socket: Socket)
?

Comment: I am not expert in scala but from the exception, I think that one is the root cause.

Comment: i guess its more about distributed computing architecture of apache spark than about scala , hope anyone helps , thanks so much for you help

Comment: I guess this cannot be done in this way because the instance of SocketServer cannot be serialized and dispatched to any clusters as it is listening to a bound socket. Actually, I was googling for the same object instead of using netcat outside a spark application, but now it becomes clear with this unanswered question that I should look for alternatives.